# PHP SQL Query - unable to add HTML formatting

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database with three tables. A, B and C. Table A has one column: entity_id. Table B has two columns; entity_id, entity_name. Table C has two columns; entity_id, entity_body.

I am trying to use php to create an html table that displays entity_name and entity_body for all entity_id that appear in Table A.

```
$sql1 = $dbh->prepare('Select B.entity_name, C.entity_body FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.entity_id = B.entity_id 
INNER JOIN C on A.entity_id = C.entity_id');
$sql1->execute();

while ($row = $sql1->fetchObject()) {
  echo '<br><tr><td>';
  echo $row->body_value;
  echo '</td><td>';
  echo $row->title;
  echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

The above query is returning the correct database records: it shows all the relevant rows separated by a line-break.

However, the  and  HTML tags never seem to be added. The 
 tags are added. All other tags are recognised and work as expected (e.g. p, div etc.).

Is it possible to format the outputs of a query as a table with HTML tags around the cells and the rows?

Apologies if this is obvious - this is my first attempt at using php with a database. Many thanks,

Ben

Comment: Hello, i didn't quite understand the question, what's the result you wanna get ?

Comment: Are your `<tr>`s actually wrapped in a `<table>`?

Comment: Your SQL query doesn't match the object properties you're accessing. There's no `body_value` or `title` in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
  $sql1 = $dbh->prepare('Select B.entity_name, C.entity_body FROM A 
  INNER JOIN B ON A.entity_id = B.entity_id 
  INNER JOIN C on A.entity_id = C.entity_id');
  $sql1->execute();

  echo '<table width="100%">';
  while ($row = $sql1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
      echo '<tr>
              <td>';
      echo        $row->entity_body;
      echo ' </td>
             <td>';
      echo        $row->entity_name;
      echo '</td>
           </tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Thanks ksealey. Your answer has fixed it! I can't really believe it was that easy. Thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing table tag before ''

//add table tag here.

```
echo '<table>'; //you can set table style using css as well
while ($row = $sql1->fetchObject()) {  
  echo '<tr><td>'; // no need to add <br> here
  echo $row->body_value;
  echo '</td><td>';
  echo $row->title;
  echo '</td></tr>';
}

//close table tag here
echo '</table>';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Sami - your answer helped too! The addition of the table tags was key.

Comment: Glad to be helpful